# show input text only on specific value selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that it has one select, one input (text), a datepicker and the submit button. I would like to show the input text only when I m selecting one specific option on the select. I ve searced and I found a similar solutions (with radio input) , I ve made some mods but unfortunately it does'nt works..
My html form it looks like:

---

```
<select class="form-control" name="bulk_options_cust" id="action_sel">
<option value="">Choose..</option>
<option value="bulkCreateRdv">Option 1</option>
<option value="bulkCreateCall">Option 2</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="fav_filter" id="">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="new_date" value="">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
submit</button>
</div>
```

The modified script that I ve found is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var h = $("#fav_filter");
  $("#action_sel select").change(function() {
    if (this.checked && this.value == "bulkCreateCall") {
      h.show();
    } else {
      h.hide();
    }
  }).change()
});
```

I have no knowledge on Javascript so if anyone is able to find me the error or suggest another solution it will be great for me.

Cheers!

Comment: I ve put it because my project that I m working it s on php but you are right it is irrelevant. I will (try) to remove it. I apologize it;s is my first question ever..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var h = $("#fav_filter");
  $("#action_sel").change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop( "value" ) === "bulkCreateCall" ) {
      h.show();
    } else {
      h.hide();
    }
  }).change()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="bulk_options_cust" id="action_sel">
<option value="">Choose..</option>
<option value="bulkCreateRdv">Option 1</option>
<option value="bulkCreateCall">Option 2</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="fav_filter" id="">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="new_date" value="">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx SunriseM! It works just fine! I would like to ask something more: the line <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> should I have it in top of the same document of in the general header document of my cms?

Comment: Its your decision, but i prefer to put the scripts in the last part of the body so the html loads first without problems. you should read this too: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

Comment: Hello again SunriseM, what if I like to show the field in more than one of the available options? I ve tried if ($(this).prop( "value" ) === "bulkCreateCall" || === ""bulkCreateCoffe") but it didn't worked. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to write it all again. `if($(this).prop( "value" ) === "bulkCreateCall" || $(this).prop( "value" ) === "bulkCreateCoffe")`

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the form?  You don't have form tags in your html.  You going to use AJAX?  The following works, modify as you need to.  Use this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/MaineMathMan/cufkscx8/

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#action_sel").change(function()
             {
             if (this.value=="bulkCreateCall")
                { $("#showMe").show(); }
                else { $("#showMe").hide(); }
             });
    });
</script>
</head>

<select class="form-control" name="bulk_options_cust" id="action_sel">
<option value="">Choose..</option>
<option value="bulkCreateRdv">Option 1</option>
<option value="bulkCreateCall">Option 2</option>
</select>
<div id="showMe" style="display: none;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="fav_filter" id="">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="new_date" value="">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
submit</button>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the fiddle and select option 2 to see the text input.  If you want it using vanilla js let me know.